# Set timeout for verification link using Timex

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, timex

I am sending a verification link via email after saving it to my database. I want the link to have a timeout, i.e., it would be rendered invalid after a certain duration. How do I do so using Timex? I don't want to use other authentication packages like Coherence.

Comment: This made my job easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think this requirements is highly related to Timtex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need Timex at all, now assuming your DB is using naive time zone, you can use

```
# Assuming the link will expire in an hour (3600 seconds)
valid_till = NaiveDateTime.add(NaiveDateTime.utc_now(), 3600)

# Sends the verification mail
...

# Save the valid_till somewhere in the database and when user tries to use the link to verify themselves compare the current timestamp against the stored valid_till
if NaiveDateTime.utc_now > stored_valid_till, do: false
```